# Object of class Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator could not be converted to int

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->search) {
            $posts = Post::join('users', 'author_id', '=', 'users.id')
                ->where('title', 'like', '%'.$request->search.'%')
                ->Orwhere('descr', 'like', '%'.$request->search.'%')
                ->Orwhere('name', 'like', '%'.$request->search.'%')
                ->orderBy('posts.created_at', 'desc')
                ->get();
            return view('posts.index', compact('posts'));
        }
-
        $posts = Post::join('users', 'author_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->orderBy('posts.created_at', 'desc')
            ->paginate(6);

        return view('posts.index', compact('posts'));
    }
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSNFM.png)

**view**

```
@extends('layouts.layout')

@section('content')
    @if(isset($_GET['search']))
        @if(count($posts) > 5)
            <h2>Результаты поиска по запросу <?= $_GET['search'] ?></h2>
            <p class="lead">Всего найдено: {{ count($posts) }} постов</p>
        @elseif(count($posts) == 1)
            <h2>Результаты поиска по запросу <?= $_GET['search'] ?></h2>
            <p class="lead">Всего найдено: {{ count($posts) }} пост</p>
        @elseif(count($posts) == 2 || count($posts) == 3 || count($posts) == 4)
            <h2>Результаты поиска по запросу <?= $_GET['search'] ?></h2>
            <p class="lead">Всего найдено: {{ count($posts) }} поста</p>
        @else
            <h2>По запросу <?= $_GET['search'] ?> ничего не найдено</h2>
            <a href="{{ route('post.index') }}" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Отобразить все посты</a>
        @endif
    @endif

    <div class="row">
        @foreach($posts as $post)
        <div class="col-6 mt-3">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h2>{{ $post->short_title }}</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="card-img mb-2" style="background-image: url({{ $post->img ?? asset('img/default.png') }});"></div>
                    <div class="card-author mb-2">
                        <h5><span class="badge badge-secondary">Автор:</span> {{ $post->name }}</h5>
                    </div>
                    <a href="{{ route('post.show', ['id' => $post->post_id]) }}" class="btn btn-outline-danger mb-2">Посмотреть пост</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        @endforeach 
    </div>

    @if(!isset($_GET['search']))
        {{ $posts->links() }}
    @endif
@endsection
```

I am getting this error:

> Object of class Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator could not be converted to int

How to fix it?

Comment: Hey. Can you see now?

Comment: What do you do with `$posts` in your view? And does this happen when you search or on regular request?

Comment: I added my view

Comment: Can you try without the join clause? I don't see you using the user data into the view. If you still need it you would be better to create an Eloquent relation.

Answer (score 0):

The hyphen at line 29 is the source of the issue, remove it and you are ready to go, PHP tries to cast `$posts` to integer to apply `- $posts` hence the error. You also need to paginate your posts if there is a search term, it keeps the data passed to your `posts.index` view consistent. A better way to write your code:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $posts = Post::join('users', 'author_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->orderBy('posts.created_at', 'desc');

    if($request->search) {
        $posts = $posts->where('title', 'like', '%'.$request->search.'%')
            ->Orwhere('descr', 'like', '%'.$request->search.'%')
            ->Orwhere('name', 'like', '%'.$request->search.'%');
    }

    $posts = $posts->paginate(6);

    return view('posts.index', compact('posts'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view/blade file:

```
@if(sizeof($posts) > 0)
...
@endif
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).